# Obtain all Pairs of Strings which are Contained in Each Other

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a list of strings and I want to extract all pairs of strings such that the first string is a substring of the second string . However, I do not want to include pairs such that first string contains another string in that list (except for itself). I would like the output to be returned as a dataframe.

To give a simple example, consider the below list:

```
names = ['dog', 'big dog', 'big brown down', 'cat', 'small cat', 'small white cat']
```

I expect the output to look like this:

[image]

Note, the pair ('big dog', 'big brown dog') is not included because 'dog' is a substring of 'big dog'.

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: @abokey I have an image of my expected output in my question. Was there anything more you were after?

Comment: So the column `Base String` is what you're looking for ?

Comment: @abokey I would like to obtain the exact same table in the image that I have copied. That is, the output should be a dataframe with two columns, Base String and String. Each row should form a pair of strings such that the first string is a substring of the second string subject to the conditions I have described in my question. For example, the first row in the image I have copied should be included in the dataframe because "dog" is a substring "dog".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['dog', 'big dog', 'big brown dog', 'cat', 'small cat', 'small white cat']
names = sorted(names, key=len)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Base String','String'])
base_strings = [x for x in names if x in x]
used = set()

i = 0
for name in names:
    for base in base_strings:
        if name in base and base not in used:
                df.loc[i] = [name] + [base]
                used.add(base)
                i += 1
            
print(df)
```

[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E6jy.png)

Comment: Thanks @gabriel__ for your answer. The output is correct, however I am looking for a solution that can be generalised to any list (the example list I provide is just some fact data I created). Currently, your solutions uses hardcoded values 'dog" and 'cat'.

Comment: I see. I updated my solution to create base strings on the basis that they do not contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Unfortunately, the assumption that all string which do not contains spaces will be base strings does not hold for the exact data that I am working with.

Comment: I provided an answer that uses pure substrings using pythons in keyword. I do not understand your question, what do you mean by "However, I do not want to include pairs such that first string contains another string in that list (except for itself)"?

Comment: For example, row 3 in your output should not be included because Base String = "big dog" however there exists a string "dog" in the list which is a substring of the "big dog". Though, row 0 in your output should be included because Base String = "dog" and besides the string "dog", there is no other string in the list which is a substring of "dog".  Essentially, I don't want any values in the "String" column to be repeated. That is why I have imposed the above condition. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I updated my answer to avoid repeating values in the string column. this arbitrary constraint though is dependent on the order of the input data. I do not know if there is enough information available in your question for the community to give you a good solution.

Comment: I am not sure why you say it is an arbitrary constraint. The constraint is there to ensure that the String column contains all strings in the original list and has no repeated values. These seem like pretty reasonable conditions to have. Also, I don't see how this depends on the order of the input data.

Comment: I have since worked out the solution to my question. It is close to your new answer. The only difference is that you need to first sort the list in increasing order of the length of the strings. Currently you are assuming that all the base strings precedes the strings that they are substrings of. If you make that change I am happy to accept your answer.

Comment: The list is now sorted by the length of the strings. I could have achieved this earlier but the requirements were not clear. Interesting nonetheless.